# What's amiss in this Fourier convergence analysis?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I worked out this solution to this basic PDE Fourier series convergence problem, but I suspect the result is "too easy to be correct," because all the answers point to no restriction on either $m$ and $b$:

> Given this piecewise function:
>   $$f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> e^x, &-1 \leq x \leq 0,\\
> mx + b, &0 \leq x \leq 1.
> \end{cases}$$
>   Without computing out any Fourier coefficients, find out the followings:
>   (a) for waht values of $m$ and $b$, if there is any, will the full Fourier series of $f(x)$ **converge pointwise** on $-1 \leq x \leq 1$? 
>   (b) Same as the above, for **converge uniformly**? 
>   (c) For **converge in the $L^2$ sense**?

Here are my answers on each of them:

---

(a) My text says that if $f(x)$ is **piecewise smooth** on an interval, then its Fourier series **converges pointwise** on the interval. Piecewise smooth means both $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are piecewise continuous. Here, it is easy to see that $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are piecewise continuous for all real $m$'s and $b$'s. Thus there is no restriction on $m$ and $b$.

So far so good!

---

(b) My text also says **uniform convergence** demands more stringent conditions: $f(x)$ has to have a **continuous periodic extension**, besides that $f'(x)$ has to be piecewise continuous on the interval. Here, I wrote that $f(x) = e^x$ has a continuous even function in $e^{-x}$ and $f(x) = mx + b$ also has continuous shift function, thus there is no restriction again for both $m, b$ in part (b).

Now I am beginning to doubt myself: Did I miss anything here?

---

(c) Finally my text says that $f(x)$ **converges in the $L^2$ sense** if and only if $\int_{-l}^{l} | f(x) |^2 dx < \infty$. From here, we can see that both $\int_{-1}^{1} | e^x |^2 dx$ and $\int_{-1}^{1} | mx + b |^2 dx$ are finite. Thus again there is no restriction on both $m$ and $b$.

Now I am beginning to seriously second-guess myself: Is anything amiss here too?

---

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: For (a), be careful. How do fourier series converge at step discontinuities? Your function $f(x)$ will have a step discontinuity for various values of $m,b$ which will ruin pointwise convergence. In other words piecewise smooth doesn't imply continuous. You will of course have pointwise convergence on each piecewise interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about $L^2$ convergence. For pointwise convergence, you need $b=1$ otherwise is not continuos in $0\  (\diamond)$. For uniform convergence, you need to make sure that the function $f$ can be made periodically continuos; that is, you have to connect the function at its extremes. Since $f(1) = m + b = m + 1$, and $f(-1) = e^{-1}$,  you need $e^{-1} = m + 1 \implies m = e^{-1} - 1$

$\ \ \ \ \ (\diamond)$  In general, if your function is piecewise smooth, then the fourier series converges to $$\frac{f(x_0^+) + f(x_0^-)}2$$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $So if you have a piecewise smooth function and you want pointwise convergence everywhere,$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ you need to make your function continuos

Comment: Thanks! My suspicion is confirmed. Let me digest your answer and will get back with you shortly. Thanks again.

Comment: For the time being I am still focusing on your (b). I understand that I need to make $f(x)$ periodically continuous, that is to connect at their extremities, but why do you have to plug in 1 to $mx + b$ and -1 to $e^x$, and not the other way around?

Comment: Because $f$ is defined in $[-1, 1]$. So you need to impose $f(-1) = f(1)$

Comment: Thanks. Let me digest it, I am a slowpoke. :-). For the time being on (a), since you are here, my text says that $\frac{f(x_0^+) + f(x_0^-)}2$, that it is addition between the two terms. Is there any typo here? Thanks again.

Comment: @A.Magnus Oh yes, I'm sorry your text is right. I corrected :-)

Comment: OK, I think I am beginning to swallow that the left end $e^{-1}$ has to equal to right end $m \cdot 1 + b$. But why that did you make $b = 1$ here?

Comment: @A.Magnus Because you still need continuity everywhere. So the condition $b=1$, necessary to ensure continuity, still applies

Comment: Can I take it as general rule that if you need to make $f(x)$ periodically continuous, you need to connect it at their extremities? (Remember you got a slowpoke here. :-) )

Comment: @A.Magnus Yes. To see why, try to plot $f(x)$. Now just keep drawing the same figure again and again, just shifted (ie you're making it periodical). What you need for this new function to be continuos? Well the original function has to be continuos (in your problem this translates in $b=1$) and you have to connect at the extremities. It is a really intuitive condition if you think about it :-)

Comment: I am OK with $b = 1$ in order to make the 2 pieces connected. I think I misunderstood what a periodic graph is. I always think that it looks like graph of sine or cosine going off left and right like sound wave. But based on the way you said that $f(1) = f(-1)$, it looks like a closed loop. Let me know and thanks again.

Comment: @A.Magnus I don't know how to make pretty graph, but think of it this way: Graph your function $f(x)$. Your function only *exists* between $-1$ and $1$, outside that there isn't anything. But you want to extend your graph all over $\mathbb R$, so what do you do? You draw your graph again and again, so you have a lot of your "little" graphs alongside together forming one big graph. Is this big graph continuos? In order to be, it is necessary that the right side of the first little graph connects nicely to the other graph you are drawing alongside it. And what is the point you're drawing there?

Comment: Is $f(-1)$! I hope I have made myself clear

Comment: I think this question will clear up my foggy mind yesterday: If you draw the original graph, the domain interval is [-1, 1]. But when you draw a shift extension to the right, then the new interval will be [1, 3]? Or shouldn't it still be [-1, 1] to preserve the $-1 \leq x \leq 0$ and $0 \leq x \leq 1$? Let me know and thanks for being so patient.

Comment: @A.Magnus The new interval for the new graph is $[1, 3]$, but you just *add* this new graph, you dont' cancel your old one. The end result is the graph of your function from $[-1, 3]$. Now repeat until you cover all $\mathbb R$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the function is not periodic. To make it periodic, I suggest change the value at the end point, i.e., define $f$ as

$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{e^x}{\rm{ ,  }} - 1 \le x \le 0,\\
mx + b,{\rm{ }}0 \le x < 1\\
{e^{ - 1}},{\rm{  }}x = 1.
\end{array} \right .$

and extend by periodicity. Its period is of course 2.

Note that the function is plainly square integrable.
Therefore, its Fourier series converges to $f$ in the *L<sup>2</sup>* norm.

Observe also that the function is of bounded variation. Therefore, its Fourier series converges everywhere.  It converges to  *f(x)* where *f(x)* is continuous, i.e., when *x* is not equal to $0$ or $-1$ or $1$. It converges to $(1+b)/2$  when $x = 0$; it converges to *(e<sup>-1</sup>+m+b)/2* when $x$ = 1 or -1.

If $b = 1 $ and *e<sup>-1</sup>* = $m+b$, then $f$ is a continuous function of bounded variation and so its Fourier series converges uniformly to $f$.

If $b$ is not equal to $1$ and e<sup>-1</sup> is not equal to $m+b$, then its Fourier series converges uniformly in any closed subinterval not containing {0, -1, 1}  . To decide that it does not converge uniformly in the whole interval, one has to examine the local behaviour of $f$ at and near these three points.

If the Fourier series converges uniformly in $[-1, 1]$ to a function, then the function must be continuous in $[-1, 1]$. So in our case if $b$ is not equal to 1 or e<sup>-1</sup> is not equal to $m+b$, $f$ is not continuous at $0$ or at $-1$ or at $1$ and so the Fourier series cannot converge uniformly in $[-1, 1]$ .

See THeorem 23 to Theorem 29 in my article
https://037598a680dc5e00a4d1feafd699642badaa7a8c.googledrive.com/host/0B4HffVs7117IbmZ2OTdKSVBZLVk/Fourier%20Series/Convergence%20of%20Fourier%20Series.pdf